# How to set a default value for mat-select which is not available as option for the user?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular12, mat-select

I am implementing a mat-select control in a dialog. The options which are available depend on the browser language of the user. For example, if the browser language is german, only german options should be available.

This is how the mat-select control looks like in HTML:

```
<mat-select [formControlName]="options">
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let option of filterOptionsByLanguage(parameter.options)"
    [value]="option.value"
  >
    {{ option.value }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

To pre-select a value when the user opens the dialog, I simply call `this.createForm.controls.options.setValue()` with the currently selected value (stored in a SQL Server database).

My problem is that there is the possibility that the currently selected option is in a different language than the user's browser language. As this option will not be available to the user, I cannot pre-select it when the user opens the dialog.

Is there a way how I can pre-select such a value without allowing the user to also select it as an option? I basically want the value to be displayed only but as soon as the user selects something else, it is no longer available as an option.
I want the control to behave like this so in case the user does not want to select another value, the previously selected value will remain selected.

Comment: An approach I would use is using the _placeholder_ for that case. So, you show a kind of _virtual value_ (placeholder) on the selector, visible to the user but, from the select point of view, it is empty so there is no conflict with the options available.

Comment: @IgnacioLago Thanks for the suggestion! Do you have an example or another ressource about how I can implement this? Also, does this require additional code later when I programmatically read the selected value from the mat-select? If I understood you correctly, the mat-select is actually empty while the placeholder is displayed so I need a way later in my code to read the placeholder value instead of the selected value if the user has not selected anything in the dialog. Is that correct?

Comment: I do not have an exact resource about it, I am talking more about current experience than established methods. And yes, you will need to manage the absence of value, monitoring/intercepting the first change to this value. If nothing changed, use your "virtual" value, otherwise, just use the value selected by the user.

Comment: Another idea: what if you have the option initially, but remove it from the list/loop as soon as the value changes? It is selected and shown, it follows your model, and cannot be selected again after change.